# C++ operator overload calling the one with parent type parameter despite there being one with given type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, unreal-engine4

```
class FArchiveDerivedClass: public FArchive
{
public:

    virtual FArchive& operator<<(UObject*& Object) override
    {       
        Object->Serialize(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    FArchive& operator<<(UClass*& Class)
    {
        if(Class!=nullptr)
        {
            FString FullClassPath = Class->GetPathName();
            *this << FullClassPath;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

`UClass` is derived from `UObject`

My class has two operator overloads , and it always calls the `UObject` version even if I call the operator on a `UClass` pointer.

```
FArchiveDerivedClass DerivedArchive;
FArchive& Archive = DerivedArchive;
UClass* Class;
Archive << Class;
```

How do I make it call the correct version?

Comment: "*even if I call the operator on a UClass pointer.*" - but you are not. You are calling it on an `FArchive&` reference, passing it a `UClass*` as an input parameter. So, it is calling the `operator<<` that belongs to `FArchive` (or an ancestor), not to `FArchiveDerivedClass`. To call that one instead, you have to get rid of the `FArchive&` reference and use `DerivedArchive << Class` instead. Otherwise, you need to implement `operator<<` in `FArchive` (or ancestor) in such a way that it makes a virtual call that `FArchiveDerivedClass` can override.

Comment: I think the second function accepting the UClass should be declared/defined as virtual in FArchive class.

Comment: Tangential: pass pointers by value, not by reference, and, if you're not going to modify the object they point to, declare them `const`.

Comment: A `derived*` can be implicitly converted to a `base*`, but that doesn't mean that a `derived*&` can be implicitly converted to a `base*&`.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Archive << Class;
```

is the problem.

In this line, `Archive` is `FArchive&` type, not `FArchiveDerivedClass&`. To call `FArchiveDerivedClass::operator<<`, you need to declare a `FArchiveDerivedClass&` type variable, for example:

```
FArchiveDerivedClass DerivedArchive;
FArchiveDerivedClass& Archive = DerivedArchive;
UClass* Class;
Archive << Class;
```

In this example, the second variable is extraneous, and you can directly call `DerivedArchive << Class`, but I assume you might need the reference for something.